# How does one quickly load a lower-resolution version of an image for a thumbnail? Or simply, how does one best create a thumbnail image?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, nsdata

Many apps such as Tweetbot show thumbnails in their table view controllers for a much higher resolution image.

For example, this image shows a thumbnail that when tapped reveals the larger image:

[image]

I'm very confused how these images are loaded, however. My thinking would be that the original image is loaded and then shrunken down to the thumbnail size and displayed. However, I find this hard to believe as the image takes a decent amount of time to load/download at full resolution, so doing that for every single image just to shrink it would seem like it would take a decent amount of time. But these seem to load very quickly.

I'm also skeptical given that when you then tap the image it then takes a second to load before the full resolution image is shown, leading me to think that if they downloaded the full resolution before it would just be cached temporarily and loaded up instantly when the user taps it.

So I'm curious how exactly one would achieve a similar thumbnail system as in this app. Given a link to an image, such as the one shown in the image above, *how would I very quickly take the image at the URL and present it as a thumbnail*?

Comment: a possible solution is that the thumbnail image is cached in some server. instead download the full image, it request to the server for thumbnail version

Answer (score 14):

Usually there are 2 images that are created by the **server** not the client, and the server provides 2 URLs for retrieving the images, one for thumbnail and one for the full res image ((this is what happens in 90% of the applications)), so your `UIImageView` (( or whoever is responsible )) is supposed to load the thumbnail, then load the full resolution image, and cache the latter, so that when you click on it it opens quickly. Now there are many cases:

- The server is really blazing fast, and you're connected to a fast wifi, so the application can load the image relly quickly
- The image size is not really big, so loading the full res image doesn't take time anyway, you're displaying on a phone eventually.

If you want to achieve what you mentioned, this [library](https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView) can help you very much.

Comment: yes. this definitely will do the job. I use this in my apps. The server creates 3 versions (very low res, medium and highres). We load the thumb image first and then start retrieving the high res image and load it on the same image view (and cache it).

Comment: Is this true with firebase? Also the link to the library is depricated

Answer (score 10):

If you *have* to do the shrinking on device (i.e. the server doesn't provide a smaller version) you probably want to avoid loading and inflating the full-sized image in memory first. (Most of the other answers are suggesting this right now.)

Instead, you can use the `CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex` method to create a thumbnail directly from the original (compressed) data without first expanding it (by wrapping it in a CGImageSource). You can see a full example of this in Apple's Image I/O Programming Guide under [Creating a Thumbnail Image from an Image Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/ImageIOGuide/imageio_source/ikpg_source.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005462-CH218-DontLinkElementID_6).

For smallish source images, this probably doesn't have a large impact, but for a large one it can help a lot, especially with memory consumption.

Answer (score 2):

It is likely different for each application.

In the case of Tweetbot they are almost definitely fetching the thumbnail from the Twitter servers and fetching the full res only when tapping the thumbnail. So in this sense, its just a different URL and twitter is doing the thumbnailing.

Apps can do it locally as well. Apple's Photos app and Camera Roll create thumbnails as soon as you take a photo and cache them locally to show in the collection view to preserve memory. Its only when you tap on it that it loads the full resolution image from memory. There is even evidence and precedent that they don't even load the full resolution image immediately only loading an image necessary for the screen size until you pinch to zoom in then swapping it for another image.

Basically, there are many simple techniques a quick google will show to actually thumbnail an image in code. But each application's method will be specific to its unique user flow.

Comment: -that was my point.  The thumbnail image is created from the full res image and then saved separately-whether it be on a different server or locally.

Comment: So if, unlike Twitter, the service's API does not provide a thumbnail, I'm basically out of luck?

Comment: You're not out of luck entirely, but you will need to load the image and generate a thumbnail using code like jeremy suggested. This will make lists of images possible but will hurt the data transfer obviously. But I doubt a single service providing pictures doesn't provide a lower res option and beyond that almost all I've worked with provide even more options like thumbnail, low, medium, high res.

Answer (score 1):

More than likely these are separate images (the thumbnails) that have been created by resizing the original full resolution image and then saved separately from the full resolution image-the reason that the thumbnails appear to load very quickly.  I have written an application that does something similar(though it saves both the thumbnail and full res image locally).  This is the code -

```
-(void)setThumbnailDataFromImage:(UIImage *)image//image is full res image that you want a thumbnail of
{

    CGSize origImageSize = [image size];
    CGRect newRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50);
    float ratio = MAX(newRect.size.width/origImageSize.width, newRect.size.height/origImageSize.height);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newRect.size, NO, 0.0);
    //the following two lines round the edges of the thumbnail
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:newRect cornerRadius:5.0];

    [path addClip];
    CGRect projectRect;
    projectRect.size.width = ratio * origImageSize.width;
    projectRect.size.height = ratio * origImageSize.height;
    projectRect.origin.x =(newRect.size.width - projectRect.size.width)/2.0;
    projectRect.origin.y =(newRect.size.height-projectRect.size.height)/2.0;
    [image drawInRect:projectRect];
    UIImage *smallImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    if (thumbnailDataArray==nil) {
        thumbnailDataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    }
     NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(smallImage);
    if (thumbnail == nil) {

        [self setThumbnail:smallImage];
        [self setThumbnailData:data];
    }
    NSData *otherObject = UIImagePNGRepresentation(smallImage);

    [thumbnailDataArray addObject:otherObject];

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

then to load the thumbnail

```
-(UIImage *)thumbnail
{
    if (!thumbnailData) {
        return nil;
    }
    if (!thumbnail) {
        thumbnail = [UIImage imageWithData:thumbnailData];
    }
    return thumbnail;
}
```

then when the thumbnail is tapped, the full res image is loaded

Comment: this ok but by using apis it could be done a lot faster if it is a jpg or so.. CGimageCreateThumbnail or something

Answer (score 1):

> So I'm curious how exactly one would achieve a similar thumbnail
>   system as in this app. Given a link to an image, such as the one shown
>   in the image above, how would I very quickly take the image at the URL
>   and present it as a thumbnail?

I would suggest using `FilePicker` in your App.

https://www.inkfilepicker.com/

So say for example the full sized image is stored at

```
https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/JhJKMtnRDW9uLYcnkRKW
```

You can call a cropped version by using the URL

```
https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/JhJKMtnRDW9uLYcnkRKW/convert?crop=100,135,220,220
```

So you just build this URL dynamically in code to suit whatever you need.

Here's an example of it with thumbnails from the Filepicker site. 
Link here : https://www.inkfilepicker.com/products/javascript_v1/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Logically you should have low resolution version on server and you can download that to create a thumbnail using following code. Even better option is to have thumbnails on server.

You can use the following code to create aspect fit thumbnail.

```
-(UIImage*)scaleImage:(UIImage *)orgImage toSize:(CGSize)size
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
    [orgImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];
    UIImage* scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return scaledImage; 
}

- (UIImage *)fitImage:(UIImage *)orgImage toSize:(CGSize)size
{
    CGSize imageSize = orgImage.size;
    float widthRatio = (size.width/imageSize.width);
    float heightRatio = (size.height/imageSize.height);
    float factor = widthRatio < heightRatio ? widthRatio : heightRatio;
    if (factor > 1.0) {
       factor = 1.0;
    }

    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(imageSize.width * factor,
                            imageSize.height * factor);

    UIImage *img = [self scaleImage:orgImage toSize:newSize];

    return img;
}
```

Call fitImage: with the desired size of thumbnail you want to generate.

Answer (score 0):

1 solution some of the app uses is having 2 versions of image 1 is high resolution second is of low Resolution thumbnail.. thumbnail downloaded initially when user clicks on the thumbnail image it stretches the low resolution image to the big size and start downloading the high resolution image in the background.. as soon as the high resolution image download completes the lower resolution thumbnail is get replaced by the high resolution image in image view.

Another solution is to download thumbnails first and in the background start download of the high resolution images as well so that most of the time when user clicks on an thumbnail he may probably get an stored image of the high Resolution from memory..

Answer (score 0):

So you can easily make a smaller version of the large image and cache it.  There are multiple ways to do this. Note that `CGContextDrawImage(CGContextRef c, CGRect rect, CGImageRef image)`  will scale as appropriate.  You don't want to do this live scaling every time most likely, so you'll want to draw into a `CGBitmapContext` and then cache that.

Along those lines, you may find that Path has done most of the heavy lifting for you in the library they released recently:  https://github.com/path/FastImageCache

It looks to have potential from the documentation (though I haven't looked into the code yet). It appears that it will call your block to draw the image to their cache.  So a simple draw at the size they indicate will reduce it and save it to the cache.

Answer (score 0):

Use FastImageCache.

https://github.com/path/FastImageCache

It's woo-hoo! fast.

(At displaying the thumbnails once cached for silky smooth scrolling, mind you. It's not particularly magic for getting the initial thumbnail displayable faster. Having low res previews stashed someplace, like other people have pointed out, is your only help there.)